# Can GeoJSON Feature Properties contain nested objects?

Tags: geojson

According to RFC7946 Section 3.2,

> A Feature object has a member with the name "properties".  The
> value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a
> JSON null value).

For years, I've been under the impression that feature properties should be one level deep. Based on the RFC, does this mean that it's valid to store a deeply nested JSON object within the feature properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can indeed be arbitrary JSON, as demonstrated in the RFC:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-1.5